# How to print inline changes in sed?

Tags: sed

I run

```
sed -i -e 'expression1' -e 'expression2' -e 'expression3'...'expression1000' file
```

How can I view the changes that `sed` is doing in execution time?

Comment: Copy `file` before you run your command and then `diff file_backup file`.

Comment: @Cyrus After completion  I have no need. As my script take long time for completion so I want to view what it is doing in execution time.

Comment: @Theophrastus That I know too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try

```
sed -i -e 'expression1' -e 'expression2' -e 'expression3'...'expression1000' -e 'w /dev/stdout' file
```

Comment: Nice idea. I suggest to append `| diff file -`